# How to Read a List<>? Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, sql, azure, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to search for some values in my Azure SQL Database. As i understand, the data returns in a object of type List, but i dont know how to read this query and pass the values to variables.

**This is my code:**

```
List<TodoItem> items = await todoTable
            .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Text != null)
            .ToListAsync();

        MessageBox.Show(items.ToString());
```

This way, it will run a query for data that contains the "Text" field different then null.

But how can i read this list with the query data to store these values?

Running this code, i got the following:

**Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.TotalCountList'1[Project.TodoItem]**

So, how is the easiest way to read this values, and store them into variables so i can work with this data?

Thanks a lot, friends.

Comment: Can you post the code of `TodoItem`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling .ToString() on your list.  This won't give the results you expect.

Try the following, which should tell you haw many results you get back from your query.

```
MessageBox.Show(items.Count.ToString());
```

You should find this matches the number of records, then you can loop through the list contents to get at the results you want.